# Как изменить цвет ползунка QTableWidget и QTextEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss, qtablewidget, qtextedit

Как я могу изменить цвет ползунка `QScrollBar`? 
Например, на желтый, а фон за ползунком на `rgb(55, 55, 55)`.

**`P.S.`** Вы на код не смотрите, я просто экспериментировал.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(400, 400))
        self.grid_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(self.grid_layout)

        self.center = QHBoxLayout()
        self.text_ed_1 = QTextEdit()
        self.button = QPushButton()
        self.center.addWidget(central_widget)
        self.center.addWidget(self.text_ed_1)
        self.center.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.center)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.prepare_new_letter_create)
        self.table = QTableWidget(self)
        self.table.setColumnCount(1)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.table.setRowCount(1)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["","",""])
        self.count = 0
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)


    def prepare_new_letter_create(self):
            self.name = self.text_ed_1.toPlainText()
            self.text = self.text_ed_1.toPlainText()
            self.pic = QPixmap(r'C:\Users\ID2021\PycharmProjects\pythonProject7\icons\krampus.png').scaled(32, 32)
            self.time = "16:03"
            self.table.setRowCount(self.count+1)
            self.new_letter_create(self.name, self.text,self.pic,self.time)
            self.count += 1
    def new_letter_create(self, name, text, pic, time):
            widget = self.createCellWidget(pic, f'{text}', f'{time}')

            self.table.setCellWidget(self.count, 0, widget)


            self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()
            self.table.resizeRowsToContents()
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.table)

    def createCellWidget(self, pix, text, btn):
            layout = QGridLayout()
            frame = QFrame()
            frame.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 10px; background-color: rgb(255,0,0)")
            frame.setLayout(layout)
            picture = QLabel()
            picture.setPixmap(pix)
            layout.addWidget(picture, 0, 0)
            layout.addWidget(QLabel(text), 0, 1)
            button = QPushButton(btn)
            button.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 5px; background-color: rgb(55,55,55)")

            button.clicked.connect(lambda x: QMessageBox.information(self, 'clicked', f'{text}'))
            layout.addWidget(button, 1, 1)
            return frame

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сделал как вы сказали, т.е. на код не смотрел. 
Так добавил пару строк и `StyleSheet`. Цвета установите какие вам нравятся.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):           # !!!
        super().__init__()        # !!!
        
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(400, 400))
        self.grid_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(self.grid_layout)

        self.center = QHBoxLayout()
        self.text_ed_1 = QTextEdit()
        
#        self.button = QPushButton() 
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
        self.button = QPushButton(self, 
            objectName="ImageButton", 
            minimumWidth=65, minimumHeight=50
        )
        self.button.setIcon(QIcon("cat.jpg"))
        self.button.setIconSize(QSize(65, 50)) 
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
        self.center.addWidget(central_widget)
        self.center.addWidget(self.text_ed_1)
        self.center.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.center)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.prepare_new_letter_create)

        self.table = QTableWidget(self)
        self.table.setColumnCount(1)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.table.setRowCount(1)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["A","B","C"])
        self.count = 0
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)

# +++
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.table)                           # !!! +++

    def prepare_new_letter_create(self):
            self.name = self.text_ed_1.toPlainText()
            self.text = self.text_ed_1.toPlainText()
            self.pic = QPixmap(r'Ok.png').scaled(32, 32)
            self.time = "16:03"
            self.table.setRowCount(self.count+1)
            self.new_letter_create(self.name, self.text,self.pic,self.time)
            self.count += 1
            
    def new_letter_create(self, name, text, pic, time):
            widget = self.createCellWidget(pic, f'{text}', f'{time}')
            self.table.setCellWidget(self.count, 0, widget)
            self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()
            self.table.resizeRowsToContents()
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.table)

    def createCellWidget(self, pix, text, btn):
            layout = QGridLayout()
            frame = QFrame()
            frame.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 10px; background-color: rgb(255,0,0)")
            frame.setLayout(layout)
            picture = QLabel()
            picture.setPixmap(pix)
            layout.addWidget(picture, 0, 0)
            layout.addWidget(QLabel(text), 0, 1)
            button = QPushButton(btn)
            button.setStyleSheet(
                "border-radius: 5px; background-color: rgb(55,255,55)")
            
            button.clicked.connect(lambda : QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'clicked', f'<h2 style="color: #fff;">{text}</h2>'))
                
            layout.addWidget(button, 1, 1)
            return frame


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
QSS = '''
QWidget {
    background-color: #1a1a26;
}
/* VERTICAL SCROLLBAR */
QScrollBar:vertical {
    border: none;
    background: rgb(45, 45, 68);
    width: 14px;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

/*  HANDLE BAR VERTICAL */
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background-color: rgb(80, 80, 122);
    min-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical:hover{
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(185, 0, 92);
}

/* BTN TOP - SCROLLBAR */
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(59, 59, 90);
    height: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover { 
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(185, 0, 92);
}

/* BTN BOTTOM - SCROLLBAR */
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(59, 59, 90);
    height: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover { 
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:pressed { 
    background-color: rgb(185, 0, 92);
}

/* RESET ARROW */
QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
    background: none;
}
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}

/* HORIZONTAL SCROLLBAR - HOMEWORK */
QScrollBar:horizontal {
}
QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
}
QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal {
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {
}
QScrollBar::up-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::down-arrow:horizontal
{
}
QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal
{
}

QPlainTextEdit{
    background-color: #6D9886;
    border: 3px solid #7611ed;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #212121;
    font: 87 15pt \"Segoe UI Black\";
}
     
QTextEdit{
    background-color: #22222e;
    border: 3px solid #7611ed;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    font: 87 8pt \"Segoe UI Black\";
}
'''            
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setStyleSheet(QSS)                                        # +++ 
    
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**cat.jpg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ok.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):           # !!!
        super().__init__()        # !!!
        
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(400, 400))
        self.grid_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(self.grid_layout)

        self.center = QHBoxLayout()
        self.text_ed_1 = QTextEdit()
        
#        self.button = QPushButton() 
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
        self.button = QPushButton(self, 
            objectName="ImageButton", 
            minimumWidth=65, minimumHeight=50
        )
        self.button.setIcon(QIcon("cat.jpg"))
        self.button.setIconSize(QSize(65, 50)) 
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
        self.center.addWidget(central_widget)
        self.center.addWidget(self.text_ed_1)
        self.center.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.center)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.prepare_new_letter_create)

        self.table = QTableWidget(self)
        self.table.setColumnCount(1)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.table.setRowCount(1)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["A","B","C"])
        self.count = 0
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)

# +++
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.table)                           # !!! +++

    def prepare_new_letter_create(self):
            self.name = self.text_ed_1.toPlainText()
            self.text = self.text_ed_1.toPlainText()
            self.pic = QPixmap(r'lena.jpg').scaled(60, 60)
            self.time = "16:03"
            self.table.setRowCount(self.count+1)
            self.new_letter_create(self.name, self.text,self.pic,self.time)
            self.count += 1
            
    def new_letter_create(self, name, text, pic, time):
            widget = self.createCellWidget(pic, f'{text}', f'{time}')
            self.table.setCellWidget(self.count, 0, widget)
            self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()
            self.table.resizeRowsToContents()
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.table)

    def createCellWidget(self, pix, text, btn):
            layout = QGridLayout()
            frame = QFrame()
            frame.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 10px; background-color: rgb(255,0,0)")
            frame.setLayout(layout)
            picture = QLabel()
            picture.setPixmap(pix)
            layout.addWidget(picture, 0, 0, 2, 1)
            layout.addWidget(QLabel(text), 0, 1)
            button = QPushButton(btn)
            button.setStyleSheet(
                "border-radius: 5px; background-color: rgb(55,255,55)")
            
            button.clicked.connect(lambda : QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'clicked', f'<h2 style="color: #fff;">{text}</h2>'))
                
            layout.addWidget(button, 1, 1)
            return frame


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
QSS = '''
QWidget {
    background-color: #1a1a26;
}
/* VERTICAL SCROLLBAR */
QScrollBar:vertical {
    border: none;
    background: rgb(45, 45, 68);
    width: 14px;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

/*  HANDLE BAR VERTICAL */
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background-color: rgb(80, 80, 122);
    min-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical:hover{
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(185, 0, 92);
}

/* BTN TOP - SCROLLBAR */
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(59, 59, 90);
    height: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover { 
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(185, 0, 92);
}

/* BTN BOTTOM - SCROLLBAR */
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(59, 59, 90);
    height: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover { 
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:pressed { 
    background-color: rgb(185, 0, 92);
}

/* RESET ARROW */
QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
    background: none;
}
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}

/* HORIZONTAL SCROLLBAR - HOMEWORK */
QScrollBar:horizontal {
}
QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
}
QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal {
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {
}
QScrollBar::up-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::down-arrow:horizontal
{
}
QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal
{
}

QPlainTextEdit{
    background-color: #6D9886;
    border: 3px solid #7611ed;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #212121;
    font: 87 15pt \"Segoe UI Black\";
}
     
QTextEdit{
    background-color: #22222e;
    border: 3px solid #7611ed;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    font: 87 8pt \"Segoe UI Black\";
}
'''            
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setStyleSheet(QSS)                                        # +++ 
    
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибр большое!!

Comment: @Bitchdragon пожалуйста.